# How to register type in Catel ServiceLocator using config?

Tags: catel

I try to register type in ServiceLocator using app.config, for example UIVisualizerService type.

1. First I check if the type is registred in ServiceLocator.Default. It's registred.
2. Then I remove its registration and check again. As expected, it is not registred.
3. Then I run ioc.DefaultServiceLocatorConfiguration.Configure(serviceLocator) to register the type (configured in app.config) again.
4. When I check again, the type is not registered!

The problem is :
ioc.DefaultServiceLocatorConfiguration.Configure(serviceLocator) works correctly, but UIVisualizerService is not registred.

What's wrong in my code in App.xaml.cs?

```
var serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.Default;
bool canResolveType = serviceLocator.IsTypeRegistered(typeof(IUIVisualizerService));
if (canResolveType)
{
    //Expected behaviour
    serviceLocator.RemoveAllTypes(typeof(IUIVisualizerService));
    canResolveType = serviceLocator.IsTypeRegistered(typeof(IUIVisualizerService));
    if (!canResolveType)
    {
        //Expected behaviour
        Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var ioc = configuration.GetSection<IoCConfigurationSection>("ioc", "catel");
        //<catel>
        //  <ioc>
        //    <serviceLocatorConfigurations>
        //      <serviceLocatorConfiguration>
        //        <register interfaceType="Catel.Services.IUIVisualizerService" 
        //                  implementationType="Catel.Services.UIVisualizerService, Catel.MVVM" />          
        //      </serviceLocatorConfiguration>
        //    </serviceLocatorConfigurations>
        //  </ioc>
        //</catel>
        try
        {
            ioc.DefaultServiceLocatorConfiguration.Configure(serviceLocator); // to register UIVisualizerService again
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Error in App.xaml.cs, in serviceLocatorConfiguration : {0}", ex.Message));
            // if incorrect implementationType
            // ex.Message = "Argument 'serviceImplementationType' cannot be null ..."
        }
        canResolveType = serviceLocator.IsTypeRegistered(typeof(IUIVisualizerService));
        if (!canResolveType)
        {
            //Unexpected behaviour
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected behaviour"); // It works !!!
        }
        else
        {
            //Expected behaviour
            // should be here !!!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By saying "it works correctly", you mean it doesn't throw exceptions? Maybe it's because you specify the assembly name for the implementation, but not the interface?

Comment: Yes, I mean it doesn't throw exceptions. What's wrong with
 <register interfaceType="Catel.Services.IUIVisualizerService"                           implementationType="Catel.Services.UIVisualizerService, Catel.MVVM" /> ?
I have same result without ", Catel.MVVM"

Comment: Adding assembly name to interface and(or) implementation doesn't change anything. I have the same result.

Comment: Please create an issue in the issue tracker, then we can check it with unit tests. http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker/

Comment: https://catelproject.atlassian.net/browse/CTL-778